# Listing widgets (chips) that have different width, in a container

Tags: flutter, gridview, chips

I'm trying to make a container with a list of element like shown in the picture below.

I used gridView.builder to make it responsive so the elements will be next to each other and in case there's no space it will return to next line.

But the problem here is with GridView.builder the elements will all have the same fixed width, thus in my case I need the elements to have variable width (example: pickup and delivery service has a bigger width because the text is longer)

[image: picture-1-]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Wrap` widget instead. See official docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

As the video explains on the link above, it works really well with Chips, as you have in your picture.

Comment: Welcome. Next time, if you post with code, you would get a reply with relevant code that fits your own code.

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use Wrap with action chip, below is example you can refer

```
        Wrap(
          spacing: 10,
          runSpacing: 10,
          children: services
              .map(
                (data) => ActionChip(
                  label: Text(
                    data,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  elevation: 5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
```

Comment: None of the specified properties in the ActionChip, nor the Wrap widget match the desired image. The widget type in the posted image is rather a default Chip widget, and not an ActionChip. At least not without additional properties defining the shape. Do not post code that is irrelevant.